# Insert Data From Textfield in webbrowser Url

Tags: vb6

How can i get data from textfield in webbrowser url in VB6

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "http://hamariweb.com/islam/islamicnames.aspx?e=TEXT"
```

TEXT = ***at that place i want to insert text from text field***

Answer (score 1):

If your textbox control has the name Text1 then you can use the following code

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "http://hamariweb.com/islam/islamicnames.aspx?e=" & Text1.Text
```